# How to populate a v-select component with json data coming from axios.get

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am having a hard time trying to populate a v-select component with data from backend. The backend data is in json format.

The array 'items_category' is not storing the data. So I see "No data available" in my v-select. Can anyone help me. Thanks. This is my code:

```
<v-select v-model="category" :items="items_category" chips dense></v-select>

data () {
  return {
    category: '',
    items_category: [],
    categories: [],
    i: 0
  }
},

created () {
  this.initialize()
},

methods: {
    initialize () {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/categories', {
            })
                .then(response => { 
                    this.categories = response.data

                    for (this.i=0; this.i<this.categories.length; this.i++) {
                        this.items_category[this.i] = this.categories[this.i].category_name
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            }) 
    }
}
```

This is my json (http://localhost:4000/categories):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "Name 1",
    "category_description": "Description 1"
  },   
  {
    "id": 2,
    "category_name": "Premium",
    "category_description": "Description 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "category_name": "Free",
    "category_description": "Description 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it correct by using the push method

```
this.items_category.push(this.categories[this.i].category_name)
```

Comment: Also `i` do not have to be inside `data` if you use it only for the `for` loop.